# Routing a subnet to global network on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, subnet

I have a host A which is connected to a global network and a local subnet. It's IPs are `77.37.194.100` and `10.1.1.1` respectively. There's server B (`77.37.195.255`) on the global network.

Another box C is connected to the subnet with IP `10.1.1.15`. How to configure routing so that B is reachable from C?

PS: Global network is ISP's network, server B is a name server and C is a Virtual Box. A and C are Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you virtual machine, add a default route to your A box

```
route add default gw 10.1.1.1
```

Also you'll have to enable ip forwarding and masquerading on the A box : take a look at [this article](http://linux.about.com/od/ubusrv_doc/a/ubusg18t03.htm) . Anyway the command for that will looks like:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/8 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: @nambuls: Wow! This magic worked!